# Spring security custom authentication filter does not redirect to asked URL 404

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-security

I am strugguling with custom authentication filter in spring security.

### What I want to do

I want to be able to have a http basic authentication (done).
Now i want to add a facebook authentication. But as I am on Google app engine i have trouble using Spring Social Facebook because i have to redifine everything. So the solution i want to put in place is a authentication filter that check the token against Facebook API (using [restfb](http://restfb.com/)).

### What I did

I implemented a new AuthenticationFilter that will get the facebook token in the headers, call the Facebook API and then I look for a user with the provided ID in my users (I created already for my FB account).

**security-context.xml**

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <b:bean id="SecurityCorsFilter" class="com.ibeacons._00_presentation.utils.SecurityCorsFilter"/>
    <b:bean id="FacebookAuthenticationFilter" class="com.ibeacons._02_services.auth.FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter">
        <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </b:bean>

    <http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless">
        <http-basic/>
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/management/register" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/client/register" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/management/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/client/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')" />
        <custom-filter ref="SecurityCorsFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="FacebookAuthenticationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="socialUserAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

</b:beans>
```

In my filter I had to redefine the doFilter to continue the chain to the basic authentication in case no Facebook header is found.

**FacebookAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter.class.getCanonicalName());

    public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "X-FacebookToken";

    public FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/client/**");
    } 

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another method to authenticate request headers 
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Attempt facebook authentication");
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        if(token == null) {
            logger.info("No Facebook token found");
            return null;
        }
        logger.info("Facebook token found: "+token);
        Authentication userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(token);
        if(userAuthenticationToken == null) throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Facebook Token"));
        logger.info("Authentication: "+userAuthenticationToken);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(userAuthenticationToken);
    }


    /**
     * authenticate the user based on token
     * @return
     */
    private Authentication authUserByToken(String token) {
        if(token==null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_4);
            User facebookUser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
            return new FacebookToken(facebookUser.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            return;
        }

        Authentication authResult;

        try {
            authResult = attemptAuthentication(request, response);
            if (authResult == null) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            getSuccessHandler().onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
        }
        catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException failed) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);

            return;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
            // Authentication failed
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);

            return;
        }

        successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }
}
```

### My Problem

The problem I face is:

```
[INFO] sept. 17, 2015 11:50:46 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
[INFO] AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

But i just want to continue on the current request.

I am using:

- spring 4.2.0.RELEASE
- spring security 4.0.2.RELEASE

The real question is what do I have to do to redirect to the asked URL after the authentication in my filter ? And is it in the filter that there is an issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a way to make it work. I changed the type of filter by a **OncePerRequestFilter** one.

**FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter.class.getCanonicalName());

    public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "X-FacebookToken";

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    private RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher;

    public final void setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(String requestMatcher) {
        this.requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(requestMatcher);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate user with Facebook token
     */
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        if(token == null) {
            logger.info("No Facebook token found");
            return null;
        }

        Authentication userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(token);
        if(userAuthenticationToken == null) throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Facebook Token"));

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(userAuthenticationToken);
    }


    /**
     * authenticate the user based on token
     * @return
     */
    private Authentication authUserByToken(String token) {
        if(token==null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_4);
            User facebookUser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
            return new FacebookToken(facebookUser.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
            logger.info("Attempt facebook authentication");
            Authentication authentication = attemptAuthentication(request,response);
            if (authentication != null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether this filter should attempt to process a login request for the
     * current invocation.
     * <p>
     * It strips any parameters from the "path" section of the request URL (such as the
     * jsessionid parameter in <em>http://host/myapp/index.html;jsessionid=blah</em>)
     * before matching against the <code>filterProcessesUrl</code> property.
     * <p>
     * Subclasses may override for special requirements, such as Tapestry integration.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if the filter should attempt authentication,
     * <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        return requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

Feel tree to propose a clever or cleaner solution :)

Comment: you don't need manually set authentication to security context if your authentication is satisfied by any of auth providers. Spring handles event (if everything goes right) and set authentication object to it's holder

Comment: It seems i have to because it prevent the BasicAuthenticationFilter to try to authenticate the user.

Comment: authenticationManager.authenticate(<...>) is calling ProviderManager which delegates to providers (like UserPasswordAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider and so on), but before invoking it's inner processing, each provider checks if it can be applied on passed *Token. So UserPasswordBasedToken kad be used on basic-provider (basic auth), where FacebookUserToken can be used only for specific provider. If any of providers is invoked (due to above condition), ProviderManager publishes auth event to do some stuff AND set auth object to spring context.